# Testing SSL v3 Support in Python

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I’m extracting the SSL certificate from a website using the socket + ssl library in python. My understanding that it connects using the preferred method used by the server.

Using this method I’m able to identify what version of SSL is used to connect, but I also need to identify whether the website supports SSL v3, in the case when the default connection is TLS.

Is there a way to identify this information without manually testing multiple SSL connections?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sites advertise what they support. Rather, it's negotiated between client and server.

You could use the excellent server tester at www.ssllabs.com. It will try lots of configurations and report what the server in question supports. (Hopefully the site doesn't support SSL v3!)